# Implementing a bit-swap hack in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Given a byte `b` of 8 bits, the following formula returns the bits of `b` "swapped" (0 and 7 are swapped, 1 and 6 are swapped, etc.):

```
(b * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023
```

When I have a function implementing this hack, namely

```
def reverseBits(b):
    return (b * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023
```

then I get an overflow:

> OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer

How can I implement the bit-swapping hack in Python?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Python 2 doesn't even have a bytes type; what's the type of `b`?

Comment: b is a string, that's what's causing the error.

Comment: @Wooble: Good question. What is the most appropriate Python substitute for the byte type?

Comment: That doesn't even work with my c runtime. At least I don't see why `0xf0` should become `0xe7`.

Comment: @Voo: You are probably using 32-bit ints, this relies on 64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @Wooble: There is no integer overflow used here, and it works for me with the values I've tested.

Comment: @Randomblue: I'm pretty sure your OverflowError comes from somewhere else. Do you get it by simply calling `print reverseBits(1)` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work as you expect:

```
def sb(b):
    return (b * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023

def harness(i):
    print '{:4}: {} -> {}'.format(i,bin(i)[2:].zfill(8),bin(sb(i))[2:].zfill(8))    

for i in range(256):
    harness(i)
```

Prints:

```
   0: 00000000 -> 00000000
   1: 00000001 -> 10000000
   2: 00000010 -> 01000000
   3: 00000011 -> 11000000
   4: 00000100 -> 00100000
   5: 00000101 -> 10100000
   6: 00000110 -> 01100000
   ...
 248: 11111000 -> 00011111
 249: 11111001 -> 10011111
 250: 11111010 -> 01011111
 251: 11111011 -> 11011111
 252: 11111100 -> 00111111
 253: 11111101 -> 10111111
 254: 11111110 -> 01111111
 255: 11111111 -> 11111111
```

This algorithm (and others) are found [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious). As stated, this method only works for a BYTE, so you will need to use another method for a larger bit pattern.

**Edit**

BTW: You can do bit reversal without any fear of overflow or math problems and for larger bit fields by using string manipulation:

```
>>> w=32
>>> s=bin(1234567)[2:].zfill(w)
>>> rb=s[::-1]
>>> s
'00000000000100101101011010000111'
>>> rb
'11100001011010110100100000000000'
```

Then convert back to an int this way:

```
int(rb,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case seems to be that b is a one-character string and not just a number, and through the multiplication you thus create a really huge array. I would suggest that you either struct.unpack() the input data (which comes from a file I guess), or use ord() & chr() as in the example below.

Surely not the fastest solution, but from what I can tell it works.

```
def rev(x):
    return chr((ord(x) * 0x0202020202  & 0x010884422010) % 1023)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("reverse_testfile", "wb") as o:
        with open("testfile", "rb") as f:
            o.write(''.join(map(rev, f.read())))
```